# SilverStripe overwriting URLSegmentFilter static

Tags: php, silverstripe

`URLSegmentFilter` has a static array `$default_replacements` which holds, among others, the string to convert ampersands to (from & to *-and-*) for URL's.

I'm trying to extend the class and overwrite this static to **translate** the ampersand convert (only value is english *and*).

How can I overwrite the owner static for this goal?

```
class URLSegmentFilterExtension extends Extension {

    private static $default_replacements = array(
        '/&amp;/u' => '-and-', // I need to translate this using _t()
        '/&/u' => '-and-', // And this one
        '/\s|\+/u' => '-',
        '/[_.]+/u' => '-', 
        '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]+/u' => '', 
        '/[\/\?=#]+/u' => '-', 
        '/[\-]{2,}/u' => '-', 
        '/^[\-]+/u' => '',
        '/[\-]+$/u' => ''
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: The `URLSegmentFilter` mainly operates in the CMS context, where you usually just have a single locale (depending on the settings of the editing Member). So using `_t()` alone might not be very helpful? So you'd probably have to get the current editing locale (assuming you're using Fluent or Translatable) and set the locale for translations temporarily.

I don't see a way to hook in translations via an Extension there. I think you'd be better off creating a custom subclass and use it via Injector.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
class TranslatedURLSegmentFilter extends URLSegmentFilter
{
    public function getReplacements()
    {
        $currentLocale = i18n::get_locale();
        $contentLocale = Translatable::get_current_locale();
        // temporarily set the locale to the content locale
        i18n::set_locale($contentLocale);

        $replacements = parent::getReplacements();
        // merge in our custom replacements
        $replacements = array_merge($replacements, array(
            '/&amp;/u' => _t('TranslatedURLSegmentFilter.UrlAnd', '-and-'),
            '/&/u' => _t('TranslatedURLSegmentFilter.UrlAnd', '-and-')
        ));

        // reset to CMS locale
        i18n::set_locale($currentLocale);
        return $replacements;
    }
}
```

Then you have to enable the custom `URLSegmentFilter` via config by putting something like this in your `mysite/_config/config.yml` file:

```
Injector:
  URLSegmentFilter:
    class: TranslatedURLSegmentFilter
```

**Update**: The above example assumes you're using the **Translatable** module. If you're using **Fluent**, replace the following line:

```
$contentLocale = Translatable::get_current_locale();
```

with:

```
$contentLocale = Fluent::current_locale();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input bummzack. Though I don't use any translation mod. I want to base the translation on the CMS locale and this can differ for each user.

Comment: @Faloude That seems illogical though? So if one Admin has `en` as locale, he'll save pages with `-and-` in the URL, and another Admin that is logged in with `de` will generate URLs that contain `-und-`? For the frontend user, this will result in mixed types of URLs, depending on who saved the page? That can't be what you want…

Comment: In any case, it should be really simple to alter my proposed solution to work without a translation-module. Just remove the unneeded lines of code and you're set.

Comment: for my purpose that is logical :-) your solution worked without translation mod by simply removing the Translatable method call & set_locale

Answer (score 1):

You can update configuration dynamically in `mysite/_config.php`

```
$defaultReplacements = Config::inst()->get('URLSegmentFilter', 'default_replacements');

$translatedAnd = _t('URLSegmentFilter.And','-and-');
$defaultReplacements['/&amp;/u'] = $translatedAnd;
$defaultReplacements['/&/u'] = $translatedAnd;

Config::inst()->Update('URLSegmentFilter', 'default_replacements', $defaultReplacements);
```

Comment: That's not really enabling translations… just setting the value to something else initially. Since URLs are generated when saving a page from within the CMS, you'd have to change the value dynamically, depending on the content locale in the CMS.

Comment: @bummzack I agree with you. However you can reuse the same code for different language installations (many domains) with preset locale (with _ss_environment.php) as well.

Comment: True, but then you could just replace the value in the config and don't bother to use `_t` at all?

Comment: I've tested this, and tried a similar solution before. But `_t()` function doesn't work in config.php.. right?